# reinitialize an object with self.__init__(...)

Tags: python

Could anybody explain whether it is safe to reinitialize an object by calling "self.**init**(". as shown in the following simplified example?

The reason i'm asking is that i couldn't find this method neither in several python books nor in internet. There are some who suggest to list all attributes and set them to initial value one by one. Basically i want to set my object to initial state after it has finished some tasks.

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self,name,author):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.copies = 5

    def reset(self):
        self.__init__(self.name,self.author)

    def incrementCopy(self):
        self.copies += 1

Kite = Book('kite runner','khaled hosseini')

print 'initial number of copies:', Kite.copies
Kite.incrementCopy()
Kite.incrementCopy()
Kite.incrementCopy()
print '3 copies are added:', Kite.copies
Kite.reset()
print 'number of copies are reinitialized', Kite.copies


initial number of copies: 5
3 copies are added: 8
number of copies are reinitialized 5
```

Comment: Why can't you do that in `reset` function itself, after you will have to pass the initial values again? `self.name` and `self.author` accesses the current value, not the initial.

Comment: self.name and self.author are not going to be changed, they can be ignored in this example. My question is about self.__init__ part. I didn't quite understand your question. What do you mean by "that"?

Answer (score 41):

The only thing special about `__init__` is that it is called automatically when an instance is created.  Other than that it is a normal method, and it is safe to use it to set your object back to its initial state.

That being said, just because it is safe doesn't mean it is a good idea.  Other people looking at your code might be confused by it, and it isn't difficult to do everything in a `reset` method (that `__init__` can even call) to be more explicit about how the method is being used.

Answer (score 32):

I would consider it a very bad practice - you should not `__init__` manually (unless calling `__init__` of the parent class). Also, passing object's data back to `__init__` is somewhat strange.

Why not something like this:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self,name,author):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.copies = 5
```

Comment: +1. The standard solution (not just in Python, but in most languages with constructors) is to factor out the code needed by both the constructor and the regular function(s).

Comment: Only problem with this is I get code lint warnings: "Instance attribute copies defined outside of __init__"

Comment: yeah, recommended way seems to be to create all the attributes in `__init__`, frankly speaking I prefer to ignore it and avoid duplication.

Answer (score 7):

I consider is not unsafe, I have used it and nothing strange happens in the memory, but take into account that attributes defined in other methods will not be reset. Consider for example:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 4
    def plus_one(self):
        self.x += 1
    def define_other_variables(self):
        self.y = 3
    def reset(self):
        self.__init__()
D = Dummy()
print(D.x) # 4
# print(D.y) will raise an AttributeError
D.plus_one()
D.plus_one()
# D.y do not exist
D.define_other_variables()
# D.y exist
print(D.x) # 6
D.reset()
print(D.x) # 4
print(D.y) # 3, still exist!!
```

Then, just remember to define every object in the **init** function. you could consider bad practice for this reason but I still think is elegant.