# Reset variables within object to initialized values

Tags: python, initialization, reset

here's a newb Python question that I'm sure is a no-brainer for the pros.  I have an object OddStream that is called from the function print_from_stream to create a list of odd numbers starting from 1.  It works find the first time but when calling it a second time the new list starts from the last number of the first list + 2.

What should I write to reset OddStream?  BTW, this is only a portion of the code, but it's the part that matters.  Thanks if you can help.

```
class OddStream(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = 1

    def get_next(self):
        to_return = self.current
        self.current += 2  
        return to_return 


def print_from_stream(n): 
    for _ in range(n):
        print(stream.get_next())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `stream` instance of the `OddStream` class is being instantiated like this:

```
class OddStream(object):
    # ...

stream = OddStream()  # Breakpoint 1

def print_from_stream(n): 
    for _ in range(n):
        print(stream.get_next()) # Breakpoint 2
```

- At breakpoint 1 `stream` has been instantiated and `stream.current` = 1
- At breakpoint 2 `stream.get_next()` has been called and it has increased `stream.current`

So the behaviour you described should be expected.

To avoid such behaviour, add a `reset()` method to `OddStream` and call it from `print_from_stream()`:

```
class OddStream(object):
    # ...

    def reset(self):
        self.current = 1

stream = OddStream()

def print_from_stream(n):
    stream.reset()
    for _ in range(n):
        print(stream.get_next())


print("First run:")
print_from_stream(10)
print("Second run:")
print_from_stream(10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Adding reset() to the class definitions and calling it from the print function solved the problem.

Comment: Update: Now that I understand the syntax, I realized I could also call stream.__init__ from within the print function.  That avoids having to add a reset() definition to the OddStream class.  However, reset() is more obvious and better for debugging.

Comment: You could find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091221/reinitialize-an-object-with-self-init) useful.